# Numpy probabilities

Tags: python, numpy

I was just wondering why I'm getting an error from running the code below. I'm trying to use numpy to do probabilities for a text-based game. The code below is not what will be in the game itself. This is just for testing purposes and to learn. Thanks for your answers in advance, and please go easy on me.

```
from numpy.random import choice

class container:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inv = {'common': ['blunt sword', 'blunt axe'], 'uncommon': ['Dynasty bow', 'Axe', 'Sword'], 'rare': ['Sharp axe'], 'epic': ['Great Sword']}
        self.probabilities = {"common": 50, 'uncommon':25, 'rare': 10, 'epic': 3}
        self.item = choice(self.inv(choice(self.probabilities.keys(), p=self.probabilities.values())))

    def open(self):
        return f'You loot {self.item}'


loot = container().open()
print(loot)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1115, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    loot = container().open()
  File "test.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.item = choice(self.inv(choice(self.probabilities.keys(), p=self.probabilities.values())))
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1117, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: 'a' must be 1-dimensional or an integer
```

Comment: Hi, @Johny , if you think the below answer was appropriate, i kindly request you to accept it as a verified answer, since it helps other users who might look into this in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) it takes in a 1D array or int `a` and a probability vector `p`whose length is equal to length of `a` and sums to one. In your case you are feeding `probabilities.keys()` and `inv.keys()` which are of type `dict_keys`. Also, your probability vector doesn't sum to 1. one way to convert the probability vector to the required format is to divide it by the sum of it. I have make the necessary changes to the code

```
from numpy.random import choice

class container:

def __init__(self):
    self.inv = {'common': ['blunt sword', 'blunt axe'], 'uncommon': ['Dynasty bow', 'Axe', 'Sword'], 'rare': ['Sharp axe'], 'epic': ['Great Sword']}
    self.probabilities = {"common": 50, 'uncommon':25, 'rare': 10, 'epic': 3}
    self.convert_prob_vector()
    self.item = choice(self.inv[choice(list(self.probabilities.keys()), p=self.probabilities_new)])

def convert_prob_vector(self):
    self.probabilities_new = [x / sum(self.probabilities.values()) for x in self.probabilities.values()]
def open(self):
    return f'You loot {self.item}'


loot = container().open()
print(loot)
```

> **Sample Output**

> You loot Dynasty bow